# Unix "mail" command wrapping text?

Tags: shell, unix, outlook

I've noticed that sometimes when I `mail` myself SQL*Plus log files, the resulting message doesn't match the log file.

For example, take the below example SQL*Plus log file:

```
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_a;
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_b;
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_c;
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_d;
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_e;
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_f;
SQL>
SQL> QUIT
```

I send it to myself using: `cat sql.log | mail me@email.com`

---

When it arrives, it looks like:

```
SQL> SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f 
SQL> FROM some_table_a; SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, 
SQL> column_e, column_f FROM some_table_b; SELECT column_a, column_b, 
SQL> column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_c; SELECT 
SQL> column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM 
SQL> some_table_d; SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, 
SQL> column_e, column_f FROM some_table_e; SELECT column_a, column_b, 
SQL> column_c, column_d, column_e, column_f FROM some_table_f;
SQL> 
SQL> QUIT
```

Its almost like the `mail` command is wrapping the lines, gluing on the next line, and adding more `SQL>` wherever it sees fit.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing this?  Why would it do this in the first place?

---

**edit:**  With 99% of logs and files, there's no mangling of the lines.  It's only every once in a while that it happens.  I suspect it has something to do with there being a `>` on most lines.

Answer (score 1):

Oh crap, I figured it out.

Unix `mail` isn't to blame, it's **Microsoft Outlook**.

I just noticed that near the `TO:` line, there's a section that says `Extra line breaks in this message were removed`.  When I click it, I can select `Restore line breaks` and I'm good to go.

---

**edit:** I've attached images for the solution.

**Option:**
[image: Option to restore line breaks for a single message]

**Permanent Fix:**
[image]

Comment: One of the (many) reasons I don't like Outlook (or Thunderbird, although it's not quite at the same level). If I get an e-mail about a LOLCat, I don't want it to burn my waffle and reformat my dog - I just want to read my e-mail...